# No data available in Table PHP

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, datatables, codeigniter-3

Why does my datatable is not displaying my data whenever i switch account? but if i'm on the admin account i can see the data of the table what is happening? i don't understand can someone please help me?

here is my index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var manageTable;
var base_url = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>";

$(document).ready(function() {

  // initialize the datatable 
  manageTable = $('#manageTable').DataTable({
    'ajax': base_url + 'maincat/fetchMainCatData',
    'order': [],
  });

});
</script>
```

and here is my controller

```
    public function fetchMainCatData()
    {
        if(!in_array('viewMaincat', $this->permission)) {
            redirect('dashboard', 'refresh');
        }
        
        $result = array('data' => array());

        $data = $this->model_maincat->getMainCatData();

        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
           
            

            // button
            $buttons = '';
            if(in_array('updateMaincat', $this->permission)) {
                $buttons .= '<a href="'.base_url('maincat/update/'.$value['id']).'" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>';
            }

            if(in_array('deleteMaincat', $this->permission)) { 
                $buttons .= ($value['button_status'] == 1) ? ' <button style="display:none;" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="removeFunc('.$value['id'].')" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#removeModal"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>' : '<button style="margin-left: 5px;" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="removeFunc('.$value['id'].')" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#removeModal"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>';
            }
            


            $availability = ($value['active'] == 1) ? '<span class="label label-success">Active</span>' : '<span class="label label-danger">Inactive</span>';

            $result['data'][$key] = array(
                $value['name'],

                $availability,
                $buttons
            );
        } // /foreach

        echo json_encode($result);
    }
}
```

here is the model:

```
public function getMainCatData($id = null)
    {
        if($id) {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_main_category where id = ?";
            $query = $this->db->query($sql, array($id));
            return $query->row_array();
        }   

        $user_id = $this->session->userdata('id');
        if($user_id == 1) {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_main_category ORDER BY id DESC";
            $query = $this->db->query($sql);
            return $query->result_array(); 
        }
        else {
            
            $user_data = $this->model_users->getUserData($user_id);
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_main_category ORDER BY id DESC";
            $query = $this->db->query($sql);

            $data = array();

            return $data;       
        }
    }
```

it was working fine in admin account but whenver i switch account it display no data

[image]

but if the account is admin here is the data

[image]

what is my problem here i don't quite understand why it's giving me an empty data whenever i switch account? same model and controller using

Comment: Hi, there is a lot to unpack here. I feel like most of the code is irrelevent. I don't feel like your question is on the creation of new data, this part could be ignored. Could you, please, edit your question and only include the relevant code ?

Comment: You seams to populate your data from the returns value of the `$this->model_maincat->getMainCatData()` function. When you are not connected as admin, what is the return value of this function ?

Comment: i don't quite understand how can i see the return value when i'm not as admin sir? @Nicolas

Comment: Ideally, you would use a debugger such as "xdebug". If you don't have one configured, you could use a `var_dump`. In either case, you need to be "signed in" as a non admin user and try to reload the page.

Comment: @Nicolas where can i configured my non admin method? both are using 1 controller and view what should I add based on the above program?

Comment: You don't need two method. But something is telling me the `getMainCatData` is using the connected account to build a query, and returns the data. Your problem might be in this method. Could you add the code of this method in your question ?

Comment: the `$this->model_maincat->getMainCatData()` give me an value of `data
: 
[["Meals", "<span class="label label-success">Active</span>",…],…]
0
: 
["Meals", "<span class="label label-success">Active</span>",…]
1
: 
["Drinks", "<span class="label label-success">Active</span>",…]`

Comment: @Nicolas done i updated it

Comment: @wloleo you are literally returning an empty array..  Replace with *return $query->result_array(); * instead of *return $data* which is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the id of your admin account is `1`, when you are using a non admin account, you are going through the `else` portion of your if, in the `getMainCatData` function.

This function is fetching the data from the database, however, it is always returning an empty array:

```php
        }
        else {
            
            /* ... */

            $data = array();

            return $data;       
        }
```

You might want to return the value of the query instead:

```php
        }
        else {
            
            /* ... */

            $query = $this->db->query($sql);
            
            return $query->result_array();     
        }
```

Note. Both your `if` and `else` block seams to be doing the same thing, I'm not sure that `if` is necessary.